# reactor java How to add a Mono<String> to a Mono<List<String>>

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm a newbie to project reactor. I have a question, How to add a Mono to a Mono<List>?(I know I can use Mono.block method to get String from Mono, but I want to learn the correct reactive way, so Mono.block is not accepted.)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class Classroom {

    private Mono<List<String>> classroom = Mono.just(new ArrayList<String>());
    
    public void addStudent(Mono<String> student) {
        //add the Mono<String> student to Mono<List<String>> classroom
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mergeWith()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#mergeWith-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-) operator to merge `Mono<String>` with the `Mono<List<String>`:

```
public static void addStudent(Mono<String> student) {
    classroom = classroom.flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable).mergeWith(student).collectList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I got this compile error, "The method map(Function<? super String,? extends R>) in the type Mono<String> is not applicable for the arguments (List::of)" @Lefteris

Comment: It's working for me. What version of Java you are using? Post your code, please.

Comment: jdk8,  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> <version>2.5.4</version>

Comment: `List::of` introduced in JDK 9. I have edited my answer for JDK 8.

Comment: Thanks, In method addStudent I want to add Mono<String> to class Property, public void addStudent(Mono<String> student) {
        //this.classroom.add(student); //if not Mono type
    }